# IncludeOS hello world failing

Tags: c++, kvm, conan, unikernel

I would like to look into [IncludeOS and run their hello world](https://www.includeos.org). I am on Ubuntu and did install the [required dependencies](https://github.com/includeos/IncludeOS/blob/master/README.md). The program exits with an error. **What am I doing wrong here?**

```
apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev git cmake clang-6.0 gcc nasm make qemu
pip3 install setuptools wheel conan psutil jsonschema
conan config install https://github.com/includeos/conan_config.git
```

I followed the installation instructions and used the `clang-6.0-linux-x86_64` profile, as is recommended for Linux. The profiles are listed [here](https://github.com/includeos/conan_config/tree/master/profiles)

```
git clone https://github.com/includeos/hello_world.git
mkdir your_build_dir && cd "$_"
conan install ../hello_world -pr <your_conan_profile>
source activate.sh
cmake ../hello_world
cmake --build .
boot hello
```

The program crashes when calling it with the boot command.

The output (some paths altered) when calling `boot hello -dv` (verbose, debug)

```
* <boot>:  VERBOSE mode set for environment
* <VMRunner>:  Loading default config. 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from /path/to/vm.vanilla.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features " 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from ./vm.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " {'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} " 
* <VMRunner>:  {'description': 'Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features', 'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} 
* <boot>:  Args to pass to VM:  []
* <boot>:  1 VM initialized. Commencing build- and boot...
* <VMRunner>:  Loading default config. 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from path/to/vm.vanilla.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features " 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from ./vm.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " {'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} " 
* <VMRunner>:  {'description': 'Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features', 'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} 
* <boot>:  Booting in debug mode
* <boot>:  No file extension. Trying to boot as kernel
* <VMRunner>:  VM boot, timeout:  None multiboot:  True Kernel_args:   image_name:  hello 
* <VMRunner>:  Booting with multiboot: True kernel_args:   image_name: hello 
* <qemu>:  KVM ON 
* <VMRunner>:  File magic:  hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

* <VMRunner>:  Found 64-bit ELF, need chainloader 
Looking for chainloader: 
Found /path/to/chainloader Type:  /path/to/chainloader: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

* <VMRunner>:  Booting hello directly without bootloader (multiboot / -kernel args) 
* <VMRunner>:  Command: sudo qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -cpu kvm64,+rdrand,+rdseed -kernel /path/to/chainloader -append "" -initrd hello "" -s -m 128 -nographic 
[ WARNING ] Running with sudo
* <qemu>:  Started process PID  1343 
* <VMRunner>:  Event loop done. Exit status: None poll: 1 
* <VMRunner>:  No poll - getting final output 
* <VMRunner>:  Exit called with status 1 ( PROGRAM_FAILURE ) 
* <VMRunner>:  Message: process exited Keep running:  False 
* <VMRunner>:  Calling on_exit 
* <VMRunner>:  Program exit called with status 1 ( PROGRAM_FAILURE ) 
* <VMRunner>:  Stopping all vms 

[ PROGRAM_FAILURE ] process exited
```

Comment: Hi! seems like qemu is not installed, did you check it? Which specific profile are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I found the answer: Hardware virtualization was disabled on my machine. I solved it by using [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox).

...such a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 3):

can you confirm that qemu-system-x86_64 is installed on this system ? I think i got the same issue when running without qemu installed.

```
(conanenv) kristian@kristian-Zephyrus:~/git/hello_world/build$ boot hello -v
* <boot>:  VERBOSE mode set for environment
* <VMRunner>:  Loading default config. 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from /home/kristian/.conan/data/vmrunner/0.16.0/includeos/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/vmrunner/vm.vanilla.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features " 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from ./vm.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " {'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} " 
* <VMRunner>:  {'description': 'Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features', 'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} 
* <boot>:  Args to pass to VM:  []
* <boot>:  1 VM initialized. Commencing build- and boot...
* <VMRunner>:  Loading default config. 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from /home/kristian/.conan/data/vmrunner/0.16.0/includeos/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/vmrunner/vm.vanilla.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features " 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from ./vm.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " {'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} " 
* <VMRunner>:  {'description': 'Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features', 'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} 
* <boot>:  No file extension. Trying to boot as kernel
* <VMRunner>:  VM boot, timeout:  None multiboot:  True Kernel_args:   image_name:  hello 
* <VMRunner>:  Booting with multiboot: True kernel_args:   image_name: hello 
* <qemu>:  KVM ON 
* <VMRunner>:  File magic:  hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

* <VMRunner>:  Found 64-bit ELF, need chainloader 
Looking for chainloader: 
Found /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader Type:  /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

* <VMRunner>:  Booting hello directly without bootloader (multiboot / -kernel args) 
* <VMRunner>:  Command: sudo qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -cpu kvm64,+rdrand,+rdseed -kernel /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader -append "" -initrd hello "" -m 128 -nographic 
[ WARNING ] Running with sudo
* <qemu>:  Started process PID  14648 
* <VMRunner>:  Event loop done. Exit status: None poll: 1 
* <VMRunner>:  No poll - getting final output 
* <VMRunner>:  Exit called with status 1 ( PROGRAM_FAILURE ) 
* <VMRunner>:  Message: process exited Keep running:  False 
* <VMRunner>:  Calling on_exit 
* <VMRunner>:  Program exit called with status 1 ( PROGRAM_FAILURE ) 
* <VMRunner>:  Stopping all vms
```

sudo apt-get install qemu

```
(conanenv) kristian@kristian-Zephyrus:~/git/hello_world/build$ boot hello -v
* <boot>:  VERBOSE mode set for environment
* <VMRunner>:  Loading default config. 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from /home/kristian/.conan/data/vmrunner/0.16.0/includeos/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/vmrunner/vm.vanilla.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features " 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from ./vm.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " {'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} " 
* <VMRunner>:  {'description': 'Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features', 'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} 
* <boot>:  Args to pass to VM:  []
* <boot>:  1 VM initialized. Commencing build- and boot...
* <VMRunner>:  Loading default config. 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from /home/kristian/.conan/data/vmrunner/0.16.0/includeos/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/vmrunner/vm.vanilla.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features " 
* <VMRunner>:  Trying to load config from ./vm.json 
* <VMRunner>:  Successfully loaded vm config 
* <VMRunner>:  " {'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} " 
* <VMRunner>:  {'description': 'Single virtio nic with vanilla cpu features', 'net': [], 'image': 'service.img', 'mem': 128} 
* <boot>:  No file extension. Trying to boot as kernel
* <VMRunner>:  VM boot, timeout:  None multiboot:  True Kernel_args:   image_name:  hello 
* <VMRunner>:  Booting with multiboot: True kernel_args:   image_name: hello 
* <qemu>:  KVM ON 
* <VMRunner>:  File magic:  hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

* <VMRunner>:  Found 64-bit ELF, need chainloader 
Looking for chainloader: 
Found /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader Type:  /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

* <VMRunner>:  Booting hello directly without bootloader (multiboot / -kernel args) 
* <VMRunner>:  Command: sudo qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -cpu kvm64,+rdrand,+rdseed -kernel /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader -append "" -initrd hello "" -m 128 -nographic 
[ WARNING ] Running with sudo
* <qemu>:  Started process PID  16622 
* Multiboot begin: 0x9500
* Multiboot cmdline @ 0x22e019: /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader ""
* Multiboot end: 0x22e09e
* Module list @ 0x22e000
         * Module @ 0x22f000
         * Args: hello ""
         * End: 0x393978
 * Multiboot end: 0x393978
<Multiboot>Booted with multiboot
        * Boot flags: 0x24f
        * Valid memory (130559 Kib):
          0x00000000 - 0x0009fbff (639 Kib)
          0x00100000 - 0x07fdffff (129920 Kib)

        * Booted with parameters @ 0x22e019: /home/kristian/.conan/data/chainloader/0.15.1-5/includeos/latest/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/bin/chainloader ""
        * Multiboot provided memory map  (7 entries @ 0x9000)
          0x0000000000 - 0x000009fbff FREE (639 Kb.)
          0x000009fc00 - 0x000009ffff RESERVED (1 Kb.)
          0x00000f0000 - 0x00000fffff RESERVED (64 Kb.)
          0x0000100000 - 0x0007fdffff FREE (129920 Kb.)
          0x0007fe0000 - 0x0007ffffff RESERVED (128 Kb.)
          0x00feffc000 - 0x00feffffff RESERVED (16 Kb.)
          0x00fffc0000 - 0x00ffffffff RESERVED (256 Kb.)

<Multiboot>OS loaded with 1 modules
        * hello "" @ 0x22f000 - 0x393978, size: 1460600b
* Multiboot begin: 0x9500
* Multiboot end: 0x326840
[x86_64 PC] constructor
[ Machine ] Initializing heap
[ Machine ] Main memory detected as 130441024 b
[ Machine ] Reserving 1048576 b for machine use
<Multiboot>Booted with multiboot
        * Boot flags: 0x24f
        * Valid memory (130559 Kib):
          0x00000000 - 0x0009fbff (639 Kib)
          0x00100000 - 0x07fdffff (129920 Kib)

        * Booted with parameters @ 0x8000: hello ""
        * Multiboot provided memory map  (7 entries @ 0x9000)
          0x0000000000 - 0x000009fbff FREE (639 Kb.)
          0x000009fc00 - 0x000009ffff RESERVED (1 Kb.)
          0x00000f0000 - 0x00000fffff RESERVED (64 Kb.)
          0x0000100000 - 0x0007fdffff FREE (129920 Kb.)
          0x0007fe0000 - 0x0007ffffff RESERVED (128 Kb.)
          0x00feffc000 - 0x00feffffff RESERVED (16 Kb.)
          0x00fffc0000 - 0x00ffffffff RESERVED (256 Kb.)
================================================================================
 IncludeOS 0.15.1-5 (x86_64 / 64-bit)
 +--> Running [ Hello world - OS included ]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Hello world
       [ main ] returned with status 0

^C[ WARNING ] Process interrupted - stopping vms
* <VMRunner>:  Exit called with status 70 ( ABORT ) 
* <VMRunner>:  Message: Process terminated by user Keep running:  False 
* <VMRunner>:  Calling on_exit 
* <VMRunner>:  Program exit called with status 70 ( ABORT ) 
* <VMRunner>:  Stopping all vms 
* <VMRunner>:  Stopping hello PID 16622 with -SIGTERM 
* <VMRunner>:   + child process  16623 

[ ABORT ] Process terminated by user
```

Comment: Hi Kristin, thank you very much for you help. I already have `qemu-system-x86_64` installed. I still get the same error. Do you have a different suggestion? Also my terminal says `(conanenv) (base)` instead of just `(conanenv)`

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to start `hello` with qemu directly? Like `qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=hello`?

Comment: my qemu version is 1:3.1+dfsg-2ubuntu3.4

Comment: I also tried a fresh start with the `gcc-7.3.0-linux-x86_64` profile, but this does not help either

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by installing the other missing `qemu` packages. Not all of these are required, but I ran

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm qemu virt-manager virt-viewer
```

I also made sure I was able to run the command `qemu-system-x86_64`
Source: https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-and-configure-qemu-in-ubuntu/